# Time trend in DF unit root test

Tags: panel-data, trend, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have a couple of questions concerning the time trend (βt) in an augmented Dickey-Fuller test for panel data:

1) From what I understand there is no clear rule/standard or test as to when to include a time trend in a DF model or not. Do I understand this correctly?

2) What would be a good methodology to study whether the inclusion of a time trend is appropriate; simply plotting the variable over time and see if there is a trend?

3) How to determine the direction of the trend (β coefficient) in a DF model?

4) It was my understanding that the rejection of the H0: =0 (non-stationarity) implied stationarity (<0) and convergence over time. Following an article (see source),  and β can however be interpreted as follows:

,β,process

=0,=0,divergence

<0,=0,convergence

<0,<0,catching-up

<0,>0,lagging-behind

=0,<0,loose catching-up

=0,>0,loose lagging-behind

I don't understand why a negative β would represent a catching-up process and a positive lagging-behind; it seems counterintuitive.

Source: https://www.academia.edu/3051335/Income_convergence_the_Dickey-Fuller_test_under_the_simultaneous_presence_of_stochastic_and_deterministic_trends